# Vite not Minifying CSS despite being explicitly enabled in the config

Tags: javascript, vite

I am currently working on a project using Vite, and I want the stylesheets to be minified, but I can't figure out how to implement this. My CSS files in the public/style directory do not get minified after building the project with my current setup.

Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default {
    build: {
        minify: 'esbuild',
    },
};
```

Output of `npm run build`:

```
$ npm run build

> kagerou@0.1.2 build
> vite build

vite v4.4.8 building for production...
✓ 2 modules transformed.
dist/index.html  5.20 kB │ gzip: 1.66 kB
✓ built in 46ms
```

[Here](https://github.com/elderguardian/kagerou/tree/site_optimizations) is a link to the branch I am currently developing on.

Before posting I tried explicitly enabling minification, to use terser instead of esbuild and vite minify plugins.

Comment: Vite is built on-top of rollup. You can probably add [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-css-porter) and adjust your vite.config.js to achieve minification of your CSS.

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you very much!